# XSLT replace single quotation sign with two single quotation signs

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, escaping, quotation-marks

I'm writing XSLT code to parse data from an XML. Value of one element contains single quotation marks which I need to escape. 
I was trying to do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="text"><xsl:value-of select='desc_text'/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="replace($text, '&apos;', '&apos;&apos;')"/>
```

but I get an error:
xsl:value-of : could not compile select expression 'replace($text, ''', '''')'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="replace($text, &quot;'&quot;, &quot;''&quot;)"/>`, in XPath 2.0 and later you could also use (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#prod-xpath31-StringLiteral) `<xsl:value-of select="replace($text, '''', '''''')"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be much simpler (and easier to read) if you switch the delimiters around:

```
<xsl:value-of select='replace($text, "&apos;", "&apos;&apos;")'/>
```

---

P.S.

Instead of:

```
<xsl:variable name="text"><xsl:value-of select='desc_text'/></xsl:variable>
```

do:

```
<xsl:variable name="text" select="desc_text"/>
```

---

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRK9